# I would like to add form information to an already existing user in a table in a database (with PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am writing a dynamic web page.  The specific problem I am having is dealing with taking form information and adding it to a user in a table in a database that already exists.

So, I have a landing page where someone enters their name, email and password.  This works fine, and a user is created in the table in my database with the respective information included.  I then reroute them to a page where I ask them to fill out more information.  I automatically fill out their name and email fields with php.  I have set up rules that prevent a duplicate email address.  But I just want to add the additional information to the same user in the table in the database.

What I used to add the information to the database the first time they enter info:

```
//Insert user into the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO `tablename`
        (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `salt`, `password`)
        VALUES
        ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$salt', '$password')";
```

What command do I use to add information to the same user on the next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

May I recommend this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)?